# SVG grid overlaid image

Tags: html, svg

I'm not even sure how to explain this.

I have a floor layout that is in a JPG format, I would like to enable user to mouseOver or click on different area of the map to get dynamically information about it.  To get different area of the map interactive, I was thinking I could overlaid a dynamically SVG grid on top/or behind it, that way, I can assign the dynamic data to a grid coordinates.

I am having problem with implementing this, I can't get the grid and the image to resize with each other.  Also, since the SVG grid is dynamic, when the image is bigger, by default, the my grid has more lines which throws the coordinates off when zoom in/out.

Is there away to generate a fixed grid (e.g., 20x10) matched and overlaid it to the image.  Make it zoom with the image?  I just got started with SVG today so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code in Angular2

```
<svg attr.width="{{w}}" attr.height="{{h}}" id="mySVG">
    <image xlink:href="../asset/building.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%"/>
    <rect x="0" y="0" attr.width="{{w}}" attr.height="{{h}}" stroke="black" fill="url(#GridPattern)" stroke-width="5"
        class="hello"/>

     <defs>
        <pattern id="GridPattern" x="0" y="0" attr.width="{{wGap}}" attr.height="{{hGap}}" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <line x1="0" y1="0" attr.x2="{{wGap}}" y2="0" stroke="lightblue" stroke-width="1px" />
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" attr.y2="{{hGap}}" stroke="lightblue" stroke-width="1px" />
        </pattern> 
    </defs>

    <g id="group1" fill="red">
    <!--<rect x="1cm" y="1cm" width="1cm" height="1cm"/>
    <rect x="3cm" y="1cm" width="1cm" height="1cm"/>-->
    <text *ngFor="let h of loc"  attr.x="{{h.x*wGap}}" attr.y="{{h.y*hGap}}" fill="red" text-anchor='middle'>{{h.text}},h:{{h.y*hGap}},w:{{h.x*wGap}}</text>
    <text *ngFor="let x of xNum; let i = index"  attr.x="{{i*wGap}}" y="20" fill="red" style="writing-mode: tb; glyph-orientation-vertical: 0;
                              letter-spacing: -3;" >{{i}}</text>
    <text *ngFor="let x of yNum; let i = index"  x="20" attr.y="{{i*hGap}}" fill="red">{{i}}</text>
  </g>



</svg>



   import {Component, OnInit,NgZone} from '@angular/core';


    @Component({
        selector: 'home',
        template: require('./home.html')
    })

    export class Home implements OnInit{
        bol:boolean = true;

        w:number;
        h:number;
        wGap:number;
        hGap:number;
        hMultiplier:number = 30;
        wMultiplier:number = 40;
        yNum = new Array(this.hMultiplier);
        xNum = new Array(this.wMultiplier);
        hLine:any;
        wLine:any;

        loc:Object[] = [{x:37,y:3,text:"testing 1"},
                        {x:31,y:25,text:"testing 2"},
                        {x:2,y:9,text:"testing 3"},
                        {x:35,y:8,text:"testing 4"},
                        {x:22,y:10,text:"testing 5"}]
        constructor(ngZone:NgZone){
            console.log(this.xNum,this.yNum)
            console.log(window.innerHeight, window.innerWidth);
            this.w = window.innerWidth-50;
            this.h = window.innerHeight-200;
             this.wGap = Math.ceil(this.w/this.wMultiplier);
                    this.hGap = Math.ceil(this.h/this.hMultiplier);

                    //////
                    //this.calculateLocation();
            window.onresize = (e)=>{
                ngZone.run(()=>{
                    console.log(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
                    //this.w = document.getElementById('bldImg')['width'];
                    //this.h = document.getElementById('bldImg')['height'];
                    this.w = window.innerWidth-50;
                    this.h = window.innerHeight-200;
                    this.wGap = Math.ceil(this.w/this.wGap);
                    this.hGap = Math.ceil(this.h/this.hGap);

                    //////
                   // this.calculateLocation();
                    console.log(this.wGap)
                    console.log(this.hGap)
                });
            }
        }
        ngOnInit(){

        }


    }
```

Comment: Show the code you have so far so we can see where you're going wrong.

Comment: Robert, I posted the code, I got the grid to generate on top of the image, the only program is zooming, the grid spacing stays the same.

Comment: Have you considered using an [image map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map)? It would be a much simpler solution.

Comment: I will look into it, never heard of it before.  thanks Paul

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it using svg tag and create my own interactive map using Angular version 4 you can view the plnkr in this link - Please view the code

```
<svg
  version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 2000 800">
  <svg:path
    *ngFor="let country of countries; let i = index"
    [attr.data-index]="i"
    (mouseover)="countryHover = country.country_country"
    (click)="clicked(i)"
    class="blob"
    [class.selected]="hasCountry(i)"
    [attr.d]="country.country_path"
    fill="currentColor">
  </svg:path>
</svg>
```

[Image of the Output incase if Plunker doesnt work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr5d2.jpg)

https://plnkr.co/edit/2heVmd7l4UokqR2OcNgm?p=preview